# Is there a Event-Based Non-Blocking Multi-threaded HTTP Request System in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to 250, Setting `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` and `SetMinThreads` in that order to 250 and Using Async/Await while sending a constantly while() loop stream of requests results in a maximum of arround 5000-6000 checks per second in good runs (may differ slightly). I want to try an achieve some kind of greater speed of sending out HTTP Requests then this.

I tried using `DefaultConnectionLimit`, `SetMinThreads`, `SetMaxThreads`, `new Thread(() => Function()).Start()` and tons others, the issue stands however that I can never achieve great speed. I dont need these to run synchronously at all, and I dont need the function to return a bool or anything either.

The code im currently using (C#) to achieve my current speed using everything ive tried using only what I felt was the best choices to use for speed and performance:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int threads, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<T, Action> body) => Task.WhenAll(
    from item in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(threads)
    select Task.Run(async delegate {
        using (item) {
            while (item.MoveNext()) {
                #region If Stopped, break the loop
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    break;
                }
                #endregion
                //run the item on the worker function
                await Task.Run(worker(item.Current));
            }
        }
    })
);
```

I heard about Non-Blocking Event-Based Threading from someone who used GO (and a library supporting this system) to create a Web-Crawler that can send/receive http requests/responses at a MUCH greater speed, as told by him it can do 2,000 requests per second on average but can spike up to 25,000 a second.

The main worker code the Web-Crawler uses seems to be:

```
func (w *WorkerContext) Worker(results chan<- File) {
    for {
        job, err := w.Queue.Dequeue()
        switch err {
        case goque.ErrEmpty:
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
            continue

        case goque.ErrDBClosed:
            return

        case nil:
            w.step(results, job)

        default:
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

It uses 1000 GoRoutines which are apparently around 8 "real" threads (Im not familiar with GO)

Is it possible to achieve some kind of thread system like this with C#? If not, why? I believe the library used by said Web-Crawler is: https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp

Comment: Since your work is IO bound, not CPU bound, you don't really need multiple threads at all.  Unless you're doing some long running in-memory processing of the results of those network requests, or doing lots of long running work to figure out what requests to make.

Comment: @Servy So I am essentially getting urls and sending them through `async`, in `worker()` (see updated code in post) is where I send the actual request, get response and deal with the response, which does store such data in memory. This queue could take a long time to finish, it could even be up to millions of total requests.